# Tweepy for python: 401 error

Tags: python-3.x, twitter-oauth, tweepy

Ok i have seen quite a few questions for this, but none that have been asked recently. I have tried about 6 or 7 example scripts from various places and still, after 2 days, all i get is "401".

Things i have tried:

```
- many, many different scripts
- deleting my app on dev.twitter and making a new one (3 times)
- making a new account on dev.twitter
- regenerating keys on dev.twitter
- setting system time to use UTC on both windows and ubuntu
- swearing at it
```

does anyone have any other ideas? (other than scraping twitter directly XD)

(The code below is just one of thhe many examples available online. Obviously the xxxx are my actual credentials and i have checked them countless times :) )

```
import tweepy


consumer_key = "xxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxx"
access_token = "xxxx-xxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxx"


class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('Got an error with status code: ' + str(status_code))
        return True  # To continue listening

    def on_timeout(self):
        print('Timeout...')
        return True  # To continue listening


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback='127.0.0.1')
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=['#pythoncentral'])
```

# outputs "Got an error with status code: 401"

Comment: 1) you're not doing anything `on_data`. Why? 2) why is your callback URL a local IP address?

Comment: This snippet was just the last example i was trying, I have tried lots of different examples found online. I have used this both with and without the callback (is the callback important?) and i was using on_data to print the data out on the screen but i thought if i could at least get rid of the 401 that would be a start. at the moment on_data isn't even called.

Comment: Check out the [Twitter error codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) - 401 is bad authorisation. Remove the callback, and double- and triple-check you have your keys copied exactly and to the correct variables.

Comment: i read that the 401 can come from a time stamp issue too, hance changing my system times to UTC. believe me, i have copied them across, checked them double checked them, triple checked them for about 3 days now, on several apps, with several accounts, on 2 machines. i'm pretty sure its not the auth codes... unless twitter are giving me the wrong codes

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Have you re-installed or upgraded `tweepy`?

Comment: ooo now thats a point, I'm using `Python3.5` at the moment. installed `tweepy` using `pip3`. never actually checked the version it installed. will double check the versions and requirements. There are no errors being displayed (bad syntax etc..) so i assumed it was the correct version, but i guess there is no harm in checking :).

Comment: I have the same and not able to fix on OSX

Comment: @baklarz2048 yeah, I gave up on this and found a different package. Looks like a lot of people have this issue but it is either un-fixable or not worth fixing.